# Validity of an argument for an implication of NP-Completeness

Tags: co.combinatorics, matching-theory, np

Fedor Petrov has posed a notorious problem regarding the existence of a matching in this question: [Resolution of multiple edges](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325477/resolution-of-multiple-edges)

As I see it the setting is a constrained bipartite matching and thus, because there is more than a single constraint, is an NP-complete problem (c.f. [Itai, Rodeh, Itai and Tanimoto: Some Matching Problems for Bipartite Graphs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwijttuR-4L6AhUwRvEDHQ89DWQ4ChAWegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.technion.ac.il%2F%7Eitai%2Fpublications%2FAlgorithms%2FTanimoto.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2UKY968mwS2ZkrR9nmTbeZ))
leading to the following

> **Questions:**
>
> - is Fedor's problem indeed NP-complete?
> - is being NP-complete sufficient to prove the existence of instances without solution?

Comment: A problem $P$ being NP-complete means that you can solve any NP problem using a hypothetical algorithm for $P$. An algorithm for $P$ with just positive instances is useless (it just always says "yes" no matter what you give it). So such a problem is NP-complete for Turing reductions iff P $=$ NP (for many-one reductions it is unconditionally _not_ NP-complete). Does this solve your second question, or is it something more substantial?

Comment: @VilleSalo the problem I see is that we have a constrained matching problem, which is generally NP-complete; now, knowing that a problem is NP-complete means that every instance, including those that are not acceptable, of other NP-complete problems "translate" to instances of the original (constrained matching) problem and would thus prove that not every instance of the matching problem has a solution. In my "opinion" proving the NP-completeness of a problem would therefore also prove the existence of instances without valid matching -->

Comment: @VilleSalo --> therefore Fedor Petrov's question would be answered in the negative if it *could* be shown that his problem is NP-complete; is that argument valid?